# how to check the response status and display content message accordingly in react js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

below is the code used to call the API, API is working i m getting the response data.
but want to check if the status code is 200 and 204 then need to show the content accordingly

```
// service file
export const getOrderSummary = (): Promise<TestSummary> => {
    return get('https://examplesitename/test/summary', {});
};
```

```
 const getSummaryDetails = async () => {
    const response = await getOrderSummary()
    if (response) {
      setOrderSummary(orderSummary = response)
      console.log(orderSummary) // getting orderSummary
    }
    setIsLoading(false)
  }
  useEffect(() => { 
    getSummaryDetails();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Don't you get a status code when you are console logging your data or via `response.status` , if no then there is not much you can do try using something like redux saga, thunk or react query for custom error handling.

Comment: console the response, you can access the status code via `response.status`

Comment: Thanks Gayatri and Akanksha, under console > network > header i m getting Status Code: 204, but but i put console.log(response.status) getting error (Property 'status' does not exist on type)

Answer (score 0):

I don't why you are having that issue because that shouldn't happen as said by this docs by
Mozilla :

[Link to the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status)

You can follow this code:

```
const getSummaryDetails = () =>{
   const url = 'https://examplesitename/test/summary'
   fetch(url).then(function(res)=>{
    console.log(res.status) //you will get your status code
    setOrderSummary(orderSummary = res)  
   })
   .catch(function(err){
     alert(err.message)
   })
}
```